# Unable to get the SQL function to run

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, sql-function

I'm unable to get a simple SQL function that run over rows of a tables and display it column info
Here how the SQL function looks like.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iterators() RETURNS Void AS $$
 DECLARE
    t2_row call_records%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
    FOR t2_row IN (SELECT timestamp,plain_crn INTO call_records limit 2)
    LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE t2_row.timestamp;
   END LOOP
 END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I keep getting following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t2_row"
LINE 7:     RAISE NOTICE t2_row.timestamp;
```

I'm not sure what possible syntax error the code has? Is it possible to get a bit more verbose error log or know as to what is the syntax error in code that I have to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement [`RAISE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) requires format string. It should be trivial, but should be there.

```
RAISE NOTICE '%', t2_row.timestamp;
```

Comment: @Panvel Right? Just found it.

Comment: I'm getting Integer out of range now. Any clue?

Comment: @PanvelStehule. The timestamp column is a `bigint` data type.

Comment: @PanvelStehule Any idea about it?

Comment: @Noobie - it is strange - you can try to cast to numeric before - `FOR t2_row IN (SELECT timestamp::numeric,plain_crn INTO call_records limit 2)`